# How to add UISegmentControl to CustomCell in UITableView when Clicked?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have custom Cell (from storyboard) with image, and UILabel with the cell at normal height of 44. When I click on the custom cell, I expand the cell height, click again on cell, it folds to normal height. When expanded, and in the extra space I would like to add UISegment Control. 
In didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, I add the segmentedControl, but this to make the segmented control all over the place when I click each time. I am not sure how to go about this. Should I make another custom Cell with the segmented control and load up the appropriate custom cell based if the cell is expanded or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would add the UISegmentControl when you create the cell, either with hidden = YES or place it out of the cell's bounds and set clipToBounds = YES on the cell.

Comment: I guess my problem is when I click on the cell, I force reloadData so I can force heightForCell as well as orientation changes to happen. But, this also forces call to cellForRow, and it would create the UISegmentControls yet again each time I hit cellForRow.

Comment: @ironman2012 there's a few problems with what you said. you shouldn't be reloading your data when the cell is tapped: you'll lose your scroll position and visually it will be jarring. rather, call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation. secondly, don't worry about what's created when; let the UITableView take care of that. Just make sure you're using the reuseIdentifier properly, and the tableview will create things when needed.

Comment: @ironman2012 lastly, if you want an expandable/collapsible UITableView, use a view with a button as a section header, and tapping that section header reloads that section. expanded sections have numberOfRowsInSection = 1, otherwise 0. There are some great UITableView tricks in the WWDC videos. 2011's advanced tableview session includes this expandable/collapsible technique. this will save you from a lot of band-aid coding.

Comment: Sorry, I am using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation and not reloadData. You guided me to the fix in your previous post. I ended up adding the segmentControls in my CustomViewCell, and just use Hide/Show logic. I did see some of the examples for collapsing, but what I have is a collapsable Section, and the section have rows that themselves can become collapsable...I have seen WWDC videos being mentioned many times now, so I am curious to check them out. Do you happen to know the name of the Video? Thanks again.

Comment: The video is "UITableView Changes, Tips & Tricks" at https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/. It builds on an example from 2010, which they mention.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second approach would be good. You have to add segmented control on some conditions.